# Need help in creating a selectable Card React component

Tags: reactjs, selection, card

I am trying to create a selectable Card component, meanwhile when I click the button the border changes to all the elements.. I need a one selection at the time, so when I select the first card, the second and third get no border around.

here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mcnulty-4w15m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The link is a starter template .

Comment: fixed to public

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed your code. You can check it now on
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-heyrovsky-0gwqp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Don't fix others' code for them, ESPECIALLY when their question is not valid for this site.

Comment: Ok i'll keep that in mind from now on. @Ian